# Hexagon shape boundary of QGroupBox

Tags: c++, qt, qgroupbox

Is it possible to repaint the boundaries of `QGroupBox` to shape of hexagon 
instead of rectangle?

Update:
I am able to draw hexagon shape `QGroupBox`. Can I draw outside `boudingrect` or somehow is it possible to scale up `boundingrect`??

```
QPainterPath MyGroupBox::getHexagonPath( const QPointF &pos,
                                  const QSizeF &size )
{     
    QPainterPath path;

    const double cos30 = 0.866025; 

    const double dx = 0.25 * size.width() - pos.x();  // 0.5 * size.width() - cos30;
    const double dy = 0.5  * size.height() - pos.y() - cos30;

    double x1 = pos.x(); // - 2 * dx;
    double y1 = pos.y(); // - dy;

    const double x2 = x1 + 1 * dx;
    const double x3 = x1 + 3 * dx;
    const double x4 = x4 + 4 * dx;

    const double y2 = y1 + 1 * dy;
    const double y3 = y1 + 2 * dy;

    QPolygonF hexagon;
    hexagon += QPointF( x1, y2 );
    hexagon += QPointF( x2, y1 );
    hexagon += QPointF( x3, y1 );
    hexagon += QPointF( x4, y2 );
    hexagon += QPointF( x3, y3 );
    hexagon += QPointF( x2, y3 );

    path.addPolygon( hexagon );        
    path.closeSubpath();
    return path;
}
```

Comment: It will still be a rectangle, it will just enclose a hexagon.

Comment: yes, that is actually what I needed. I need some help in reimplementing the protected virtual function `paintEvent()`.

Comment: The thing is that it might take a little more than that. The paint event is simple enough, just a paint event, but you may also need to make sure that the enclosed items will not go out of the hexagon.